# python 2.7 xml - get the value from a specific note below a note

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

He i work with IronPython 2.7 in Dynamo.
I need to get the value from a specific note in a realy big xml. I made an example xml, so you better understand by problem.
So i need to get the value of "lvl", but only in the note "to".

In the moment I get an error:

> TypeError: list objects are unhashable"

for line:

```
list.extend(elem.findall(match))
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there an better/easy way to do it?

Here is the example xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
    <note2>
        <yolo>
            <to>
                <type>
                    <game>
                        <name>Jani</name>
                        <lvl>111111</lvl>
                        <fun>2222222</fun>
                    </game>
                </type>
            </to>
            <mo>
                <type>
                    <game>
                        <name>Bani</name>
                        <lvl>3333333</lvl>
                        <fun>44444444</fun>
                    </game>
                </type>
            </mo>
        </yolo>
    </note2>
</note>
```

And here is my code:

```
import clr
import sys

clr.AddReference('ProtoGeometry')
from Autodesk.DesignScript.Geometry import *
sys.path.append("C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib")
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml="note.xml"

xpathstr=".//yolo"
match ="lvl"

list=[]

tree = ET.parse(xml)
root = tree.getroot()

specific = root.findall(xpathstr)

for elem in specific:
    list.extend(elem.findall(match))

print tree, root, specific, list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get the value of "lvl", but only in the note "to" you can do it in one xpath:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml="note.xml"
xpathstr=".//to//lvl"
tree = ET.parse(xml)
root = tree.getroot()
specific = root.findall(xpathstr)
list=[]
for elem in specific:
    list.append(elem.text)
print (list)
```

Gives:

```
['111111']
```

If you know  that there are elements "type" and "game" containing "lvl" you can alternatively use the xpath ".//to/type/game/lvl" or if element "to" has to be contained in "yolo" then use ".//yolo/to/type/game/lvl"

And you probably want to be using list.append instead of list.extend but maybe not, I don't know the rest of your code.

Comment: Hi thx for your help! Now i know how to handel xpath right. Problem solved.

Comment: You can accept the answer, by using the buttons on the left of the answer, if it has answered your question, if you like